# How to grab the file name of the position of an existing row?

Tags: php, jquery

I am created the pop up model when I am clicked the `Edit Meeting File` button in the table, my problem is how to grab the file name of the position of an existing row when I have selected?

Below is my coding:

```html
<?php
$i = 1;
$files = scandir("upload_dms_file/uploads_filing_file");
$date = $files[$a];
for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++) {

    ?>

    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $i++; ?></td>
        <td> <a href="upload_dms_file/uploads_filing_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" target="_blank"> <?php echo $files[$a]; ?></a></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a href="upload_dms_file/uploads_filing_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>"
                                                      download="<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                    Download</a></button>
            &nbsp &nbsp
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a
                        href="upload_dms_file/delete_filing_storage.php?name=uploads_filing_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                    Delete
                </a></button>

        <?php
if ($files[$a][0] == 'm') {
?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit Meeting File</button>

<?php 
}
?>
```

Pop up model box content coding:

```html
                  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         Current Filing File:
        <input value="hi"></input>


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Below is my output, for example in this ouput, I am click the No 3 `Edit Meeting File` button, then any one can guide me how to show No 3 `Filing File` name in the popup model box input. If I have clicked No 4 button, then will show No 4 `Filing File` name in the popup model box input:

[image: Output 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text you're trying to target is in the previous `td` to the `button` which is clicked. As such put a unique class on that button to make targeting it easier, then traverse the DOM to get the `text()` within the `td`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary foo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit Meeting File</button>
```

```js
$('.foo').on('click', function() {
  let filename = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();   
  $('#modal').find('input').val(filename);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Then I try to put your code replace my code, but how to show the filename in my popup model box input?

Comment: Just set the value of that input. I updated the answer for you